# How to define image, small_image, etc. automatically/programmatically

Tags: image, product-images, gallery

i noticed a strange behaviour of magento today. I have an online website  where people can buy online. Some products came without image. Thay are showing only the magento logo. How is this possible? What do you suggest in this case?
Thank you in advance!

[image: Check the link]

Answer (score 1):

You can change in list.phtml the line

```
Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(150)
```

to

```
Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(150)
```

it's untested. If that doesn't work, have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756103/magento-get-image-gallery-in-list-phtml with this you can make an array of all images attached to the product.

Comment: Is there any possibility to do this step with code, because there is not only one image missing.. there are lot of them. I have noticed this kind of behaviour after each import has finished, so... i am thinking if there is any problem with import of images, or, maybe the process of cleaning images with Imaclean? Sorry for any innconvenience but i am new in magento,so please take my apology